# Display items from mysql db by avg rating - php

Tags: php, mysql, average

I am making a movie database with a movie rating-system and I would like to display the best-rated movies by average.

Here is the structure of my database :

table movies_ratings : id | movie_id (themoviedb api) | rating
table movies : id | movie_id | title | overview | genres | poster-path | popularity (themoviedb api)

There is my class ratings in my models :

```
class Rating extends Connection {

public function rate($id, $value) {
$sql = 'INSERT INTO `movies_ratings` (`movie_id`, `rating`) VALUES(?, ?)';
$params = [$id, $value];
$req = $this->query($sql, $params);
}

public function avg($id) {
$sql = 'SELECT AVG(`rating`) AS avg FROM `movies_ratings` WHERE `movie_id` ='.$id;
$params = [$id];
return $req = $this->query($sql, $params, 'one');
}
}
```

I have made a function to display movies by popularity and it works :

```
  public function getPopularMovies($offset = null) {
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM `movies` ORDER BY `popularity` DESC';
if ($offset) $sql .= ' LIMIT '.$offset;
return $this->query($sql, null, 'all');
}
```

But I fail at making a function to display movies by rating. Could you help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

On the database side you might want to get the whole movie list at once, with the average rating. I split it over lines for readability.

```
SELECT movies.*, AVG(movie_ratings.rating) AS rating
FROM movies
LEFT JOIN movie_ratings ON movies.id = movie_ratings.id
GROUP BY movies.id
ORDER BY rating DESC
```